# Connecting AWS CN cloudfront to outside of China S3 with a fast connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, great-firewall-of-china

We have an app for having deep conversations within small communities. In most communities, the members are both from China and outside of China. We are experiencing a very slow connection between AWS CN CloudFront and our S3 bucket in Singapore.

What is the best solution to support our Chinese users?

Answer (score 0):

For content hosted in global region S3 the best option is to use EC2 proxy for your S3 global bucket.
You can use the CN CloudFront -> Optimized route -> Global NLB -> Global S3 proxy hosted on EC2/ECS/Fargate -> Global S3.
When using above solution make sure your instances can scale to meet the load (e.g. for EC2 use Auto Scaling Groups).

Comment: I don't think CF China support global NLB